# solve the differential equation by integrating directly

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation and I don't know how to solve it when it comes to integrating directly. I'd like to know how to do this so I can start doing other problems. Thanks in advance.

Solve the differential equation by integrating directly

$${{\rm d}y \over {\rm d} t} = {4t + 4 \over \left(t + 1\right)^{2}}$$

Comment: I think you mean $y_t$, although it is kind of weird nottation for a simple ODE.

Comment: @RonGordon thanks..sorry that's what I meant!...

Comment: can you please clarify whether you mean `(4t + 4) / (t + 1)^2`, or `4t + (4 / (t + 1)^2)`? I just rolled back an edit which implied you meant the former. But I'm not sure so I'm putting your earlier post back and hopefully you'll clarify.

Comment: ok I edited ...it is (4t + 4) / (t + 1)^2

Comment: OK, in that case I was mistaken in rolling back the edit, and I will reinstate it.

Comment: @TooTone Thanks for doing that. I should have been more careful with my edit in the first place.

Comment: So this problem just requires basic integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(t)=4t+\frac4{(t+1)^2}\implies y(t)=2t^2+\frac{4t}{t+1}+y(0)$$
$$y'(t)=\frac{4t+4}{(t+1)^2}\implies y'(t)=\frac{4}{t+1}\implies y(t)=4\log(t+1)+y(0)$$
The solution of the second version on the interval $(-\infty,-1)$ would be
$$
y(t)=4\log|t+1|+y(-2).
$$

Comment: @JohnHabert Have you checked it is actually not a primitive? Because it is.

Comment: Deleting other comments. I realized why you choose a more complicated form of the answer - to make evaluating at $0$ nice.

Comment: @Did how did you get y(−2) ?

Comment: If $t=-2$ then $\log|t+1|=0$